# Grails Custom Validation - Query inside validation check - What happens while updating?

Tags: grails

I have a custom validator like -

```
validator: { userEmail, userAccount ->

   if (userAccount.authenticationChannel == "ABC") {
      boolean valid = true;
      UserAccount.withNewSession {
      if (UserAccount.findByEmail(userEmail)){
         valid = false;
      }
      else if (UserAccount.findByName(userEmail)) {
         valid = false;
      }
```

...

So basically, I need some validation based on some condition and in my validation I need to execute a query.

But, now if I do -

```
def admin = new UserAccount(firstname:'Admin',email:'admin@example.com')


admin.save(flush:true)


admin.addToAuthorities("ADMIN").save(flush:true)
```

It fails.

Grails is running the validation, even on update and since email exists validation fails. How is this different if I do

`email {unique:true}`

Is Grails saying that I cannot write a custom validator which checks uniqueness.

Comment: > It fails. If you provide any exception or fail stacktrace, it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: as Olexandr stated below, a stacktrace would be very helpful. "it fails" isn't really clear.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is your issue or not, but when I tried to create a validation like this (ie. one that does queries against the database), I would get a StackOverflowError. The reason is that, when you run a query (like `findByEmail`), Hibernate will try to flush the session, which will cause it to validate all transient objects, which in turn calls your custom validator again, resulting in infinite recursion.

The trick to prevent this is to set the flush mode of the session to "manual" for a short time while running the queries. This prevents Hibernate from trying to flush the session before running the queries. The side-effect is that your query won't return entities you created in the current session but haven't been persisted (flushed) back to the database yet.

```
UserAccount.withNewSession { session ->
    session.flushMode = FlushMode.MANUAL
    try {
        if (UserAccount.findByEmail(userEmail)){
            valid = false;
        }
        else if (UserAccount.findByName(userEmail)) {
            valid = false;
        }
    }
    finally {
        session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);
    }
}
```

See [UniqueConstraint](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.grails/grails-hibernate/2.0.3/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/orm/hibernate/validation/UniqueConstraint.java) for an example of how this is done.

Comment: Hi, could you provide an updated link to your UniqueConstraint example?  That one is giving a 404 unfortunately.

Comment: Updated. Couldn't find the original file on github anymore.

Comment: Had the same problem as RockyJ. They should mention this in the documentation for the validator.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative might be to do the checks in the save method.

```
def save = {
  ..
  if (some_checks_succeed(userEmail, userAccount)) {
    admin.save(flush: true)
  }
  ..
}

def some_checks_succeed = { String userEmail, String userAccount ->
  boolean valid = true;
  if (userAccount.authenticationChannel == "ABC") {
    UserAccount.withNewSession {
    if (UserAccount.findByEmail(userEmail)) {
     valid = false;
    } else if (UserAccount.findByName(userEmail)) {
     valid = false;
    }

    ..
  }

  return valid
}
```

Some modifications might be necessary, but the above code gives you an example

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I could get this to work.The admin.save() calls validation both on insert and update. I handled both the cases (insert and update) and was able to get this working.

Thanks