# grails domain class validator + set unique constraint according to field values?

Tags: grails, model, constraints, validation, grails-orm

Is there a way to write a custom validator that will perform different validations according to field values?

For example

```
class myModel{

   A a;
   B b;
   String prop
   static belongsTo:[m:myModel]

   constraints{
       prop(validator:{
          val,obj->
                if (obj.a== null){
                  unique:[b,prop]
                }
                else{
                  unique:[a,b,prop]
                }
        })
   }
}
```

I'm quite confused about this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm too new to grails to answer your question, but I did find this other stack overflow question that may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447612/grails-custom-validation-query-inside-validation-check-what-happens-while-upd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not the most elegant solution, this should work:

```
static constraints = {
    prop(validator: { val, obj ->
        if(obj.a == null) {
            return !myModel.findWhere(b: obj.b, prop: val)
        } else {
            return !myModel.findWhere(a: obj.a, b: obj.b, prop: val)
        }
    })
}
```

I don't believe there's a way to conditionally validate uniqueness based on property values without manually performing the query.

Comment: Good answer.  Also validations such as unique correspond to schema generation so trying to apply a condition to them is not possible AFAIK.